Hose reel intake pipe with no terminal
This hose reel has a clean cut pipe with no terminal (such as male threading) as its intake. The out terminal is threaded for a hose. When connecting the intake to a source, which is a threaded hose bib, should I cut the hose to friction fit it over the straight pipe and them put a ring clamp around it?


Does the inlet pipe have a lip/edge/bump at the bottom?  Not the best, but might be made to have a hose clamp holding the hose on.

nothing, it looks like a precisely cut pipe with a grinder cutoff wheel. absolutely no terminal of any sort except its own edge

I have done it myself with no problems, but would prefer a handy shutoff valve close by that I remember to turn off every time after use(I know, a fantasy).  A compression/sharkbite fitting might be better.

my question is how to connect the hose bib that is near by to this pipe, what to put at the end of the unterminaled black nipple in order to be able to mount the other end of the hose to it?

The black nipple should be connected to a short hose/pipe from a nearby outside hose faucet.  Depending on what you trust, a hose with hose clamps, or a compression fitting/push on fitting on the nipple with adapters for the hose end(screw on, barbed).
